# Filter dataframes in python using values from another dataframes and assign labels to filtered values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and my coding is a bit rusty. Say you have two dataframes, df1 and df2

```
>>> df1 
A B
1  man
2  boy
3  girl
4  child

>>> df2 
Begin  end 
2          10
4          12
6          14
8          16
```

I want to use values from the `begin` and `end` columns from `df2` to create a second column in `df1` and label corresponding values as either before, within, or after. I have tried some codes (see below). But it has not been able to do the job for me. I get this error ‘ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()’.

```
position = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['A'] < df2['start']:
        position.append('before')
    if row['A'] > df2['begin'] and row['A'] < df2['end']:
        position.append('within')
    if row['A'] > df2['begin'] and row['A'] > df2 ['end']:
       position.append ('after')
 d1['position'] = position
```

Comment: Please show the desired output dataframe.

Comment: By df2['start'] do you mean df2['begin'] ?

Comment: Btw " row['A'] < df2['end'] " this is a comparison between a value and pd.Series. Pandas compares the value of row['A'] with every value in the column df2['end'] and returns a column of True/False. Hence the Valueerror when trying to use the result in a logical statement.

Comment: @ timeg this is my desired output. My example is not the best but if you please let me know if you need more clarification.                     
 A   B        C
1    man   before
2    boy    within
3    girl     within
4    child   within

Comment: @kubatucka I meant df2['begin']. I have made the corrections. Hope this makes the question much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes/inconsistencies in your code but here's a solution to what I think you're trying to do:

```
df1['position'] = ''
df1['position'].loc[df1.A < df2.begin] = 'before'
df1['position'].loc[df1.A > df2.end] = 'after' 
df1['position'].loc[(df1.A <= df2.end) & (df1.A >= df2.begin)] = 'within'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ran the code you provide but got this error message 
'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects', I failed to mention the two data frames don't match in terms of the index and row/column numbers.

Comment: Then i don't understand. For a  fiven row of A, which row in B do you want to compare the dates with?

Comment: The example above is hypothetical. I want to use values from df2 (I.e. begin and end) and set a range which I will use to assign labels to the values in df2. I tried to add my intended output. I appreciate your help.